# is there a way in nodejs to convert a geotiff to a PNG (using gdal_translate ?)

Tags: node.js, gdal, geotiff

Does anyone know if it is possible to use nodejs gdal to convert a geotiff to a regular png for example at the command line you would do:

```
gdal_translate -of PNG -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -scale 0 1000 test/data/test.tiff out.png
```

but i am wanting to use a NodeJS end-point and so something like

```
var gdal = require("gdal");
var dataset = gdal.open("sample.tif");
var rgba_png = dataset.getRGB();
```

There is no documentation on the following page, and i dont know if gdal has the same functions as gdal_translate

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdal

Comment: https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal/issues/67

Answer (score 0):

Try `gdal-async` - it has a library call version of `gdal_translate` - `gdal.translate()` in its latest version and it is actively developed

(Disclaimer: I am the author)